# Javascript disabled on my app all of a sudden

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-apps

My FB app has been working fine and I hadn't made any changes in a while. All of a sudden, the Javascript has stopped working and i'm not sure why. Here is a simple example of what used to work but now doesn't;

```
<a href="#" onclick="unlink(); return false;">Unlink Account</a>

<script>

    function unlink() {
    var dialog = new Dialog();
    var url = "unlink_url";
    dialog.showChoice('Unlink Account', 'Are you sure you want to unlink this account from your myFlashStore account?' ,'Yes','No');

    dialog.onconfirm = function(){ document.setLocation(url); };
}

</script>
```

Very simple code that used to work. Now when I check the source of the page, everything within the `<script>` tag is commented out and I get this message;

> Rendering the page using the following FBML retrieved from MY_URL You
>   are seeing this because you are a developer of the application and
>   this information may be useful to you in debugging.  The FBML will not
>   be shown to other users visiting this page. (dashes were replaced with
>   underscores):

I don't understand why it has stopped working, can anyone help?

Comment: are you sure you didn't violate any t&c? try creating a new (temp) app and see if the code works there - if it does it is most likely that Facebook has disabled your app because of some kind of t&c violation or user compains

Comment: Not as far as I know. The app has been running for a while, I didn't get a notification about any violations. I will give it a go on another app. Is that the only reason why it wouldn't be working now? Surely they would just disable the whole app instead of just disabling JS?

Comment: `FBML` is deprecated, it's not supported and no bugs will be fixed. And it will stop working in less than two months from now. It's time to move on!

Comment: For FB to have any control with the js, this has to be FBML (and FBJS). As @JuicyScripter sais, FBJS is no longer supported, and FBML will be removed in not to long.

Comment: @Wasim, according error message your application is rendered as FBML, check the settings to ensure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok turns out that it was that my app wasn't an iFrame app, it was the old style FMBL app. Had to change it to an iFrame app and recode quite a bit of stuff and it all worked!